# Match optional pattern preceeded by random content

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to capture two groups in the following sentence, one is **I**, the other is **optional**

```
I want to match random optional field.
```

I tried the following approach, but it's not yielding expected result:

```
(I).*?(optional)?
```

Removing the round patenthesis around **optional** can match correctly, but since I need the second match, I can't do so.

```
(I).*?optional?
```

So how can I match both groups correctly? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick with your regex is that you need to group (and discard) anything leading up to `optional` that doesn't match `optional`.

Use negative look-around (with a `?:` prepended so that the group isn't used for capture):

```
(I)(?:(?!optional).)*(optional)?.*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex:

```
(I).*(optional)
```

the pair of brackets will return you the capturing groups.

Comment: The regex you've provided makes `optional` non-optional.